# Sitecore redirects to login page even after authenticated

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7, sitecore7.2

Sitecore redirects the user to login page even after successful login. I checked the access to the page i am trying to browse, it has no read access for "extranet\everyone" and read access for the user i  am putting into the role after login is successful.("extranet\test"). Can someone suggest a solution for this problem?

Thanks
Dev

Answer (score 2):

We ran into something similar when trying to use secure cookies.  If you are, you either need to not require SSL

```xml
<httpCookies httpOnlyCookies="true" requireSSL="false" />
```

or also set the requireSSL attribute on the forms element as described [here on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.requiressl(v=vs.110).aspx).

```xml
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="member_login.aspx" cookieless="UseCookies"
    requireSSL="true" path="/MyApplication" />
</authentication>`
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't by chance have it set for DENY on EXTRANET\everyone do you? A deny will overrule an allow.